# Porque clicar no link "lista completa de perguntas" para ver todas as questões (os índices)?

Tags: suporte

Observei que isso ocorre no SOen também e queria saber porquê que na [página inicial/principal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) só aparecem inicialmente X (tava a contar uma a uma e cansei) links para as questões ativas sem os índices para acesso ao bloco das mais antigas?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Qual a ideia por detrás disto? Haveria algum problema se aparecesse desde o início?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Algumas vezes fico apenas pelas ativas, e esqueço/não vejo o link para ver as demais.

Comment: +1 Excelente pergunta, já me tinha perguntado o mesmo e acontece-me o mesmo, por preguiça não vejo mais, ainda hoje de manhã fiz isso.